# What is "dmname" in Arch linux grub config

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, configuration, dm-crypt

Hello and thanks for clicking into this for a look.

I noticed that in the arch wiki, under cryptdevice in dm-crypt you have this:

> cryptdevice
>
> This parameter will make the system prompt for the passphrase to unlock the device containing the encrypted root on a cold boot. It is parsed by the encrypt hook to identify which device contains the encrypted system:

> cryptdevice=device:dmname
>
> device is the path to the device backing the encrypted device. Usage of persistent block device naming is strongly recommended.
>
> dmname is the device-mapper name given to the device after decryption, which will be available as `/dev/mapper/dmname.`
> If a LVM contains the encrypted root, the LVM gets activated first and the volume group containing the logical volume of the encrypted root serves as device. It is then followed by the respective volume group to be mapped to root. The parameter follows the form of `cryptdevice=/dev/vgname/lvname:dmname`

In this, I want to know why do some people say `:root` while some say `cryptoroot` and still some says `vgname`. In which I am very confused as to which one should be the official one? I did `:root:allow-discards` and it worked very well. In this I ask for you take on it. This line is only edited if you want to create an encrypted arch btw.

Thanks for taking a look again and have a safe day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whatever you want for the `dmname` parameter, just make sure to use the same name when referring to the device at other places (e.g. in `fstab`) or use UUID. When opening the device manually using cryptsetup (`cryptsetup luksOpen <device> <name>`), you'll also need to specify a name, which also can be whatever you want, this is the same case. It is even possible to use a different name every time the device is opened (but that would be impractical for system devices which needs to be mounted etc.).

When opening the encrypted device, cryptsetup creates a new device mapper device on top of the encrypted device which (from system point of view) is not encrypted (system sees a "normal" device with ext4 filesystem, the only difference is that all writes to it are encrypted before writing the data to the underlying block device) and you need a name for it and as I already said, you can use any name you want. Some tools like UDisks and systemd use `luks-<UUID>` just to make sure the name is unique system wide, but it's not necessary.

This is how encrypted (unlocked) partition looks in Fedora with the `luks-<UUID>` name:

```
└─sda2                                          8:2    0 930,5G  0 part  
  └─luks-094c2ba3-eb59-48fe-83ab-eca3fe533c03 253:0    0 930,5G  0 crypt
```

and this is the `/dev/mapper` symlink:

```
$ ls -la /dev/mapper/luks*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 7 19. pro 08.25 /dev/mapper/luks-094c2ba3-eb59-48fe-83ab-eca3fe533c03 -> ../dm-0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not have it as you said it should be consistent with cryptsetup's name. Which I used lvm during live installation of arch. And putting :root:allow discards still seemed to work fine. This is my lsblk for the encrypted partition:
`sdc                       8:32   0 111.8G  0 disk  
├─sdc1                    8:33   0   500M  0 part  /boot
└─sdc2                    8:34   0 111.3G  0 part  
  └─root                254:0    0 111.3G  0 crypt 
    └─volgroup0-lv_root 254:1    0 111.3G  0 lvm   /
`

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it more clear -- the name is not saved anywhere so you can use different name every time. The only important thing is to remember to use either UUID or the same name when referring the device in config files like `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thanks for adding more to your answer! And so if I understand it correctly, after `cryptdevice=` as long as I use `UUID` or consistent `/dev/....` name system wide, it should work no matter what name I assign it after the colon of  `UUID=1234567:`, as that is just the name the system assigns the logical volume when encryption is opened. If that is correct, than I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Yes, exactly. `UUID` is usually preferred because it is not only unique but also "stable", this is mostly useful for partitions because it's not guaranteed that `sda` will be always `sda`. You are the one picking the name here so it's safe to assume it won't change.

Comment: Thanks again, I always used UUID since the fstab can still handle drives even if they are removed and replaced if they are labeled with UUIDs. I wish you a nice day!